# firefox and azureAD authentication issues

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, ansible-tower

I use firefox private window to login to Ansible tower. The Ansible tower is setup with Azure AD authentication.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/ent_auth.html#azure-active-directory-ad

When I click on Windows icon on the Ansible tower login,  Azure AD SSO window is not showing up. This used to work before.
I am not sure if its firefox or windows issue at this time. I cleared cookies and site data, which didnt help.

[image: Ansible tower login window to click on windows icon]

Any ideas on where I can check
Thanks

Comment: The redirect URL configured in the Ansible tower to login to Azure AD might not be correct. Also, please check whether pop-up blocker is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the best way , but reinstall of firefox solved the issue